# NetworkManager is not running after upgrading to Noble

Tags: network-manager, 24.04

I admit I knew this to be a long shot, but had to try it - I upgraded my 23.10 to 24.04.

After booting up, my network connectivity is gone and the Settings screen says:

[image: NetworkManager not running]

What I would usually do in this situation would be:

```
systemctl start NetworkManager
```

But it seems to be completely gone. If I try installing it (yes, I know, no internet), it says that actually `network-manager` depends on `libnetplan1` (`>= 0.106`) which is not installable.

The `packages.ubuntu.com` also returns 0 results for `libnetplan1` (there is `libnetplan0` however):
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libnetplan1&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Has anyone else had this issue? How would you proceed with triaging this?

Comment: This install was *hit* by that issue, as was another box here... alas *development* products are off-topic on this site regardless of being in *alpha* or *beta*; with Ubuntu *noble* still in *alpha*.  This isn't a Ubuntu+1 or Ubuntu-Next support site.

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: A related issue is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2055012, the solution described there might work as well.

Comment: Please note for future users... whilst this issue has already been resolved/fix (*thus this specific issue won't reoccur*), the actual problem end-users encountered depended on when they actually performed their upgrade..  thus fix actually differs too (*as packages advanced from -proposed to main; some requiring deletion from main first.. what was available varied over mere minutes/hours*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something is going wrong on Ubuntu's side, see:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2059651

As comment `#5` on that bug ticket mentioned, you can workaround this temporarily by manually download and `dpkg --force-all -i` network-manager DEB package of previous version from mirror archives.
However, there will still be many packages missing and make the system unusable (even desktop environment being removed if running `apt dist-upgrade` after this issue occurs).

Since Noble is still under active development (not reaching beta yet), this issue might get fixed in the next few days.

Update: get the machine back online with the workaround and then apt update, --fix-broken  install, install ubuntu-desktop then upgrade should fix this now.

Comment: BIG BIG Thank you! Alongside old `network-mananger`, I downloaded `libteamdctl` and `libndp` from noble and installed them as you suggested. It started working immediately :)