apt wants to remove important sounding packages
Apt suddenly said the packages libdaxctl1 libndctl6 libpmem1 are no longer needed and should be autoremoved.
these packages all sound really important. so I set them to manually installed.
can someone help me find what packages depended on them to no longer need them or what they have been replaced with? I am on kubuntu 24.04.

Why do you think they're important?   A quick look for one in what is provided on a new full install (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/noble/release/kubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) and I don't see the packages, so they've been added post-install by a user of your machine with sudo privileges

Why do you think they're important?
A quick look for one in what is provided on a new full install (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/noble/release/kubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) and I don't see the packages, so they've been added post-install by a user of your machine with sudo privileges  (as a consequence of other installs most likely)

https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libndctl6
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libdaxctl1

We're limited to details you provide us, but if I was using a Kubuntu 24.04 LTS system here, I'd not be concerned with them being removed; not with my usage of my computer, but my usage & hardware likely differs to yours.
To work out what you installed that requires them, you could try exploring apt rdepends libdaxctl1 to explore the libdaxctl1 package, or if you want to see effects use sudo apt --dry-run remove libdaxctl1  (the output of the rdepends would I'd hope trigger memories for me that will tell me why its installed, where the second --dry-run command should be even more obvious as to why it was installed, or that its not required).

I thought they are important cause when I run apt show on them, I get keywords like "managing kernel subsystem" and "low level persistent memory"

@Usermaxn, what maybe important to you will of course differ to what is included to most users. Those packages are not found on the 24.04 ISO so aren't expected on a Kubuntu install; neither is nfs-common that I consider essential (my network storage sits on remote NFS shares) so only you can decide if they're important.  Personally, I usually don't worry if apt wants to remove packages (though I still perform some quick checks if I suspect something looks wrong), as packages can always be re-installed at text terminal even if you can't login to GUI at next boot.

I'll add this as example... This box (and others of mine) sit on the development release.. During the final stage of alpha for noble (24.04) as it approached beta some problems were warned about on ML for those that watch that, or I noted when I read thru what packages would be removed (then I read the ML).  It can be see on this site too (eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508934/networkmanager-is-not-running-after-upgrading-to-noble/1508940#1508940) which didn't impact this box; but it did others. As this is my primary box I fixed the issue prior to reboot here so all was fine

but on another box I applied no fixes when I read what was to occur, and then had occurred in package upgrades.. and then tested the effects via reboot & login... I suddenly had no networking on that noble box, as was warned about on the ML posts for the unreleased noble product... Without networking I couldn't apt install to fix the situation.. but even that isn't a real problem, as it required me to find a thumb-drive with some space, walk to my primary box (in another room), download (wget) the (2) packages I needed to install, walk back to impacted box and install those

packages (dpkg -i)... then a simple networking restart & all was good... I rebooted & confirmed issue was resolved.  That issue occurred as the product wasn't yet stable (still in alpha actually even though close to reaching beta).. but that issue was still resolved rather easily & quickly...  A faster re-install method exists too, eg. when this box did have an issue I was unable to find, I actually fixed via non-destructive re-install which is possible on flavors using calamares installer (Kubuntu 24.04 LTS uses it)

You can trust the APT package management system. It will never remove dependencies if these are still required by other software on the system.
